# I don't get exceptions when I enter invalid inputs

Tags: c#, oop, exception

I have a problem with my code. When I enter an invalid input it should give me an exception but it doesn't, instead it returns me the value as if its correct.
Here is my class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace Lecture_1_Homework
{
    public class Person
    {
        private string name;
        private int age;
        private string email;

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return this.name;
            }
            set
            {
                if (!ValidateName(name))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("You need to enter your name.");
                }
                this.name = value;
            }
        }
        public int Age
        {
            get
            {
                return this.age;
            }
            set
            {
                if (!ValidateAge(age))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Your age must be between 1 and 100");
                }
                this.age = value;
            }
        }

        public string Email
        {
            get
            {
                return this.email;
            }
            set
            {
                if (!ValidateEmail(email))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid email input");
                }
                this.email = value;
            }
        }



        private bool ValidateName(string name)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        private bool ValidateAge(int age)
        {
            if (age > 100 || age < 1)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        private bool ValidateEmail(string email)
        {
            try
            {
                MailAddress mail = new MailAddress(email);
                return true;
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        public Person(string name, int age, string email)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
            this.email = email;
        }
        public Person(string name, int age)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }
        public void ToString()
        {
            Console.Write("Name:{0}\nAge:{1}\nEmail:{2}\n",this.name,this.age,string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.email) ? "no email given" : this.email);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my main

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Lecture_1_Homework
{
    class Persons_main
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Person Peter = new Person("Peter", 18, "test123@yahoo.com");
            Person Jake = new Person("Jake", 19);
            Peter.ToString();
            Jake.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

If I enter an number greater than 100 or lower than 1 it should give me an exception but it doesn't.

if I don't enter a name it should give me an exception but it doesn't.

And if I enter a wrong format for my email it should give me and exception but it doesn't.

For example if I enter for my email "test123mail.com" this should give me an exception but it doesn't.

And if I enter a " " for my name it should give me an exception but it doesn't.

I can't find my mistake and I would appreciate some help.

Comment: You're setting the value of the backing field in the constructor without actually executing your validation logic, use your property setter if you expect the constructor to throw on invalid parameter values, or check the parameter values directly in the constructor. Your property implementations should be referencing `value` when doing validation, and setting the value of your backing fields to `value` as well.

Comment: Oh... yeah thats the problem. I should really be more careful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things...

First of all, you're validating the variable *before it's been set*:

```
ValidateName(name)
```

I think you want to validate the *incoming value* for the property instead:

```
ValidateName(value)
```

Second, you're setting the backing variables *directly* without validating them:

```
this.name = name;
```

The validation is in the *property setter*, so use that instead:

```
this.Name = name;
```

Comment: Yup thats the problem. I should be more careful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you need to validate the value being passed in, not the property.

```
ValidateName(value)
```

instead of

```
ValidateName(name)
```

And when assigning the value to the property, use

```
this.Name = value; // instead of this.name
```